# Find out if random words make up sequence of words connected by last and first letter (word soccer)

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

So I have a problem here. I get set of random words and my job is to find out if there exists atleast one sequence of words that connects all words (first-last letter) in line.

For example sequence of words (apple - eagle - elephant - tiger) would return true. But sequence of words (apple - eagle - elephant - peach) would return false.

So I wanted to use some graph theory. I figured out that I could create directed graph and brute force it to find either longest path in the graph or Hamilton path. The problem here is that the graph can be cyclic so the problem would always be NP full. Is it truly the best solution or did I miss something and the problem is actually much easier?

The best would be obviously to have acyclic graph so I could use critical path algorithm to find the solution in o(n+m).

Is brute force truly my only choice or is there any other alternative way to solve this problem? At first I thought about something like counting starting and ending letters and then compare them but it had its own problems and I could not really solve them.

Anyway if brute force is my only option, is there any good way to optimalise the longest path algorithm as best as possible?

Comment: Graph theory may be overkill for this, unless you like a fun challenge. At the most basic level, you could extract the first and last letters and use itertools combinations to get the combos for comparison

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) there is an O(1.657^n) approach to the Hamilton path problem, though I suspect that it is difficult to implement.

Comment: @G.Anderson Could you expand your basic solution? If I am not wrong you would still have to go throught all option (N! complexity). Am I right?

Comment: What is the size of your lexicon, such that the complexity is of practical concern?

Comment: The existence of algorithms cited covers the problem well.  Let me pose a problem idea: do you *have* a test case in which the existence of a cycle brings you to an invalid solution?  Specifically ... first you identify all cycles.  Then code your usual algorithm such that on first encountering *any* node of a cycle, the algorithm immediately traverses the entire cycle, removing it from the remaining graph.  In what case does this cause the algorithm overall to *miss* a valid answer.

Comment: This would require a traversible graph in which removing an identified cycle then renders the remaining graph non-traversible -- i.e. disconnected.

Comment: @Prune It goes up to thousands of words.

Comment: You're correct that my solution wouldn't necessarily be any less time-complex, however it _may_ be significantly more efficient in terms of overhead and implementation (networkx for example, you have to create a node for each word, then the edges, then attributes for the first/last letters, then do the same amount of traversal) for a simple `True/False`. However, if you want to do longest-possible-list (path length) or other metrics, a graph would definitely be more robust.

Comment: @G.Anderson:  I'm thinking of the `graph` package for this.  I wanted to get a scale of the problem.  Yes, implementation and maintenance are large concerns; I'd generally take an **O(n^2)** algorithm that's easy to read over **O(n^1.657)** that only one or two of us could read.

Comment: @Prune, I think either way is valid, or even other methods. Regarding removing traversible paths: this may be a dumb idea, but what about a graph where each letter in the alphabet is a node and the words are edges/edge attributes? Then you never lose a node, just decrease the edge weights/number of attributes...

Comment: @G.Anderson  Yes, that's the straightforward graph construction.  Now trying to traverse each edge exactly once -- or, in the expanded problem, find the longest path of unique edges.

Comment: You're right, for some reason I was thinking of it backwards; A DAG with words as nodes and edge direction based on first/last letters.

Comment: @G.Anderson You can not use DAG to solve this problem because this problem is not acyclic graph but cyclic grahs. And to find all DAG you would have to use another NP complete algorithm.

Comment: As I said, I was thinking of it totally backwards to start. Thanks for helping me clarify.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence is possible only if there exist every word starting with the last character of word except for one exception which is the last word. 
A possible solution to build a hash map containing first and last character of each word and check whether it satisfies the property, be sure to mark a word after it is processed once so that it will not be iterated again.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, let me give it a shot. First, I assume that the input for this problem is something like a finite set *S* (not a multi-set) of finite length strings (words) with alphabet [a-z] (lowercase). We assume that |*S*|>=2, and for each *w* in *S*: |w|>=2. Let's say we denote a word *w* that belongs to the set *S*. Further, we denote as *f* the function that extracts the first character of a given word *w*; likewise, we denote as *l* the function that extracts the last character of a given word *w*. As an example, for *w*="hello", *f*(*w*)="h", and *l*(*w*)="o". We assume that in *S* there does not exist two words *w*, *w'* such that *f*(*w*)=*f*(*w'*) and *l*(*w*)=*l*(*w'*), this to avoid having multiple edges with the same source destination (is this a fair assumption for the game in general?). Anyhow, checking that no two words share the same first and last letters can be done in *O*(*S*) time, linear w.r.t. to the number of words.

We transform the set *S* into a directed graph (digraph) *G*=(*V*,*E*). Trivially, we first set both *V* and *E* as the empty set, then for each word *w* in *S*: *V*=*V* U {*f*(*w*)} U {*l*(*w*)}, and *E*=*E* U {(*f*(*w*),*l*(*w*))}. The previous process runs in linear time w.r.t. the input size |*S*|=|*E*| (important remark: the number of words equals the number of edges).

Now, this is where things start to get interesting. To "connect" each word you must traverse though a path that uses each edge exactly one time (words are edges, letters are vertices); this is not a Hamiltonian path but, a Eulerian path! There exists necessary and sufficient conditions for a digraph to contain an Eulerian path. The existence check can be done in linear time w.r.t. |V| (the distinct first and last letters from the original word set *S*). Furthermore, the derivation of the Eulerian path can be done in *O*(|*V*|+|*E*|) (in the worst case |*E*| dominates |*V*|, and therefore linear w.r.t. to the number of words in the set *S*).

**An algorithm to solve this**. The algorithm is based on [Hierholzer's algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167506008701584), and in case you don't want to read the paper, you can find some info [here](http://www.graph-magics.com/articles/euler.php). Here's my collected / modified algorithm:

```
//Start the existence check & initial node selection
Compute the vertices in-degrees and out-degrees.
If all vertices have the same out-degree as in-degree, then set *v*0 to any vertex of the graph.
Else If at most one vertex has out-degree - in degree = 1 & at most one vertex has in-degree - out-degree = 1, then set *v*0 to the vertex whose out-degree - in degree = 1.
Else there is no Euler path 

//Use two stacks to compute the Eulerian path using Hierholzer\'s algorithm

HEAD and TAIL both stacks empty.

Push *v*0 to HEAD.

While HEAD != empty
    While out-degree of top of stack vertex, *u* > 0
        Let *v* be a vertex neighbor of *u* (the edge (*u*, *v*) exists in *G*).
        Push *v* to HEAD. //*v* becomes new *u*
        Delete edge (*u*,*v*) from *G*
        Decrease the out-degree of *u*
    end while.
    While HEAD != empty and top vertex *u* of HEAD out-degree == 0
        Pop *u* from HEAD and Push it to TAIL
    end while.
end while.

The Eulerian path is found in order in TAIL
```

Now, you need to pop the contents from `TAIL`. There should be exactly |*E*| - 1 elements, and should be trivial to reconstruct the edges. For obtaining the words back, since there are no two words that share the same first and last letter there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between the edges and the words. If previously stored in a hash table retrieving the words order can be done in linear time w.r.t. |*E*|.

Alright, so the steps to solve this problem and the complexity:
1. Transform *S* to a graph *G*, *O*(|*S*|).
2. Verify the existence of the solution, *O*(|*S*|).
3. Derive the solution *O*(|*S*|).
4. Retrieve the word order, *O*(|*S*|).

In general, you can solve this task given the assumptions in *O*(|*S*|).

This was a fun task. Where did you get it from?